# INSERT and UPDATE(+ increase values) between two different tables php mysql

Tags: mysql, php, insert

tbl_A

[id | facility_section | assigned_no]

---

tbl_B

[col1 | col2| issued_to | col3 | col_etc]

---

The drop down list will retrieve values of `facility_section` column of `tbl_A` table. Then, the drop down list values will be inserted into `issued_to` column of `tbl_B`. Code sample:-

```html
<?php

include ('dbconnect.php');

@$i=$_POST['issued_to'];

if(@$_POST['submit'])
{
  $s="INSERT INTO tbl_B (issued_to) VALUES ('$i')";
  mysql_query($s);
}

@$facility_section = $_POST['facility_section'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT facility_section FROM tbl_A");

?>

<select name="issued_to">
  <option selected disabled>-- Please Select --</option>
  <?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<option value='" . $row['facility_section'] . "'>" . $row['facility_section'] . "</option>";
    }
  ?>
</select>
```

What I want is that, each time the drop down list values is inserted into `issued_to` column of `tbl_B`, `assigned_no` column of `tbl_A` will be updated and increased by 1 where it will be increased accordingly:- `facility_section`=`issued_to`.

I know the code to update:-

`UPDATE tbl_A
 SET assigned_no = assigned_no + 1
 WHERE facility_section = '$facility_section'`

But, I'm stuck on how to do this...

Answer (score 1):

I think you are going about this the wrong way. A fundamental principle of database design is to avoid having information that is redundant (or replicated by other information somewhere else). If same information is in two or more places, then it could be inconsistent (different in each of these places).

Firstly, is `issued_to` in table B a foreign key to table A? It should be.

Now, don't store `assigned_no` in Table A. What if someone changes this value without adding a new row to Table B? What if someone inserts to Table A, without updating the corresponding `assigned_no`. If you assume that the `assigned_no` corrseponds to the number of entries in Table B with that `issued_to`, as soon as this becomes invalid, you have a potential for lots of entries.

Instead, retrieve the number of assignments like this

```
SELECT 
    facility_section,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_B WHERE issued_to = 4551) AS assigned_no
FROM tbl_A
WHERE id = 4551
```

or for the whole table at once like this:

```
SELECT 
    a.id,
    a.facility_section,
    COUNT(*)
FROM tbl_A AS a
INNER JOIN tbl_B AS b
ON a.id = b.issued_to
GROUP BY a.id, a.facility_section
```